# Send files between android and nosejs through socket

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to build an application to transfer files between android client and a node js server. I managed to send an image from the android client , but I want to receive it with the node js server . I've tried this :

```
socket.on("image", function (image) {
                    console.log(" image réçu : " +image)
});
```

But it isn't working for me. How should I resolve this Problem  .

Answer (score 1):

### Android -> Server

Android:

```
File file = new File("/path/image.jpeg");

try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte imgByte[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    fis.read(imgByte);

    //convert byte array to base64 string
    String img64 = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(imgByte);

    //send img64 to socket.io servr
} catch (Exception e) {
   //
}
```

Server:

```
socket.on("image", function (image) {
    console.log(" image réçu : " +image)
    //use fs.writeFile

    image = image.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");

    require("fs").writeFile("out.png", image, 'base64',function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

});
```

### Server -> Android

Server:

```
fs.readFile("/img/your_img_in_server.jpeg", function(err, data){

    var img64 = new Buffer(data, 'binary').toString('base64')
    socket.emit("send_img", img64)

})
```

Android:

```
socket = IO.socket("http://localhost");
socket.on("send_img", new Emitter.Listener() {

  @Override
  public void call(Object... args) {    
    String data = (String) args[0];
    byte[] b = Base64.decode(data,Base64.DEFAULT);
    //your bitmap data
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b,0,b.length);
  }

});

socket.connect();
```

fs api: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java

These should be work (I didn't test codes).

Comment: can you please write the code ? i didn't understant what you mean

Comment: and what about sending it to the client ? i would be great if you help me

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: This is quite bad practice to load entire image in memory to send it to server. This can result in OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: @KonstantinBerkow, What is your suggestion?

Comment: @OzgurGUL, "socket.io-file" is best alternative for js-clients. It sends chunks of binary data to server so large file upload won't block other messages between client and server. Unfortunately there is no port for java which I am aware of. For now I stick with uploading files using multipart POST and then sending url or other identifier of uploaded file to server.